# Using list comprehension instead of function

Tags: python

I am trying to write a Python program that counts the number of strings where the string length is 2 or more and the first and last character are same from a given list of strings.

Sample List : `['abc', 'xyz', 'aba', '1221']` - expected answer is `2`

I have the code using a function, but am curious to know whether there is a simpler way to write it by using list comprehension.

I wrote the following code but it doesn't work. Is it because the question is unsolvable with list comprehension or because I have gotten something wrong with the code?

```
li=['abc', 'xyz', 'aba', '1221']
li.count(x for x in li if len(x)>1 and x[0] == x[-1])
```

Comment: List comprehensions need to be in brackets: `[x for x in li if len(x)>1 and x[0] == x[-1]]` should work.

Comment: `len([x for x in li if len(x) >= 2 and x[0] == x[-1]])`

Comment: Thanks CJ59. Indeed, I had forgotten to use square brackets, but even still the code you suggested didn´t work (it gives a result of 0). I think there´s an issue with the li.count, as jpp pointed out below.

Answer (score 6):

`list.count` counts occurrences of a given value in a list. More appropriate, you can use `sum` with a generator comprehension:

```
li = ['abc', 'xyz', 'aba', '1221']

res = sum((len(x) >= 2) and (x[0] == x[-1]) for x in li)  # 2
```

This works because `bool` is a subclass of `int`, i.e. `True == 1` and `False == 0`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sum` with a generator expression instead:

```
sum(1 for x in li if len(x)>1 and x[0] == x[-1])
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
li=['abc', 'xyz', 'aba', '1221']
print(len([x for x in li if len(x)>1 and x[0] == x[-1]]))
```

It is very similar to your original answer, except

remember to put [] around your list comprehension

`li.count(item)` will count how many times the item occurs in the list.
But actually you want how many items are in the list, so use `len(list)`.

Answer (score 1):

Or `len`+`filter`:

```
>>> li=['abc', 'xyz', 'aba', '1221']
>>> len(list(filter(lambda x: len(x)>1 and x[0]==x[-1],li)))
2
>>>
```

`list.count` is incapable of counting by condition nor multiple items, only one single value.

To explain mine:

- Make a `filter` object conditioning it being bigger than 1 and first element is the same as last element
- Make the `filter` object a list
- Then get the length of it.